# How to Create SMS API using Node.js

Tags: node.js, api, sms, message

I need to send notifications and special messages to my app users as an SMS. so I want to make **SMS API**. how can I create it using node.js?

Comment: You could try the SMS API provided by [Snapi SMS](https://snapisms.io/docs/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [nexmo communication API](https://www.vonage.com/communications-apis/); Run

> npm install nexmo

for the package

```
const Nexmo = require('nexmo')

const nexmo = new Nexmo({
    apiKey: '*****',
    apiSecret: '*****',
});
var to = 'numberTo';
var from = 'brandName';
var text = 'someText';
nexmo.message.sendSms(from, to, text);
```